# Run the output from Masscan in a variable using sh script

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to capture the output from masscan in a loop variable.
The intention is to process the data during a live scan
Something like

```sh
while IPST="$(masscan -iL list.txt -p80 )"   #scan masscan output in var IPS  
  do 
      # remove "Discovered open port 80/tcp on" from var $IPST and put the clean ip in var $IP 
      IP="$(IPST="$(sed s'/\[//' | sed -r 's/Discovered open port 80tcp on//') # not tested yet
      echo $IP
      ...
```

but i have no idea how to do this.
does anyone know how to do it

EDIT:  (i started trying for loops)
just realized in the shell "masscan >> filename.TXT" give the best results for me. so in a loop it would be something like.

```sh
 for I in $( masscan -iL italy.txt -p80 >> ThisIneedInAvariable.txt );  
 do
```

but i need ThisIneedInAvariable.txt you guessed it, in a variable

unfortunately this don't works

```sh
 for I in $( masscan -iL italy.txt -p80 >> $variable );  
 do
```

this gives "masscan: No such file or directory"

```sh
 for VARIABLE in $(< masscan -iL italy.txt -p80) ;  
 do
```

I need it in a loop, the complete script is based on the output from masscan and should end when masscan is done, in fact i am trying creating a stream.

Comment: Can you try to build the question to be testable by people who don't have `masscan`? Including enough of an output sample to allow testing would be a good place to start.

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is a good place to start wrt. iterating over line-oriented output. It may make more sense to process content one line at a time instead of storing the entire output in a variable before running logic on any of it.

Comment: i trying to read the output from masscan in a variable until the program ends

Comment: `masscan ... | while read IPST; do ...; done` or possibly just: `masscan ... | sed ...`